# What is the kerberos request and reply packet size?

Tags: kerberos

Can anyone how kerberos works.  any manual regarding kerberos . What is the size of packet size, what encryption is done and what are the sizes of keys etc.

Comment: All of this is too broad for SO, and totally findable on Google. SO is for small, reproducible programming problems :) For example, "This code to get the size of packets is giving this error", not just "where is the manual?"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Kerberos request and reply packet size - they are generally very small, typically around 50 - 100 kilobytes.  To understand how Kerberos works, think of a triangle.  At one point of the triangle, you have the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC).  After you have proven your identity to the KDC, it hands out a ticket to you - you being the internal network web browser user or SSH user.  You are the second point on the triangle.  This Kerberos ticket allows you access a Kerberos-protected service (such as HTTP or SSH) running on an application server on your network.  The "application server" in this scenario, is the third point of the triangle.  Two of the early and arguably most important contributors/creators of Kerberos, Clifford Neuman & Theodore Ts'o, from MIT at the time, explain how Kerberos works in this guide: [Kerberos: An Authentication Service for Computer Networks](http://gost.isi.edu/publications/kerberos-neuman-tso.htmlforge.net/index.html).  Literally, just a few paragraphs down from the top of the article is a section titled, "How Kerberos works".  This is not really a manual. It explains the Kerberos main concepts.  The article is dated but all concepts still apply. For "a manual", you need to ask yourself what you're trying to do.  Integrate a Java web application to Kerberos (using Microsoft Active Directory)? Something else?  For the former, which is very popular combination, I suggest reading this:  [Java-based Integrated Windows Authentication w/ Kerberos SPNEGO](http://spnego.source).  As mentioned, Kerberos request and reply packet sizes are generally small. Encryptions types available are DES through AES and more, encryption key sizes are 40-bit to 256-bit lengths and more, though anything smaller than 128-bit length is out of favor now.  Take a look at the [Kerberos Network Authentication Service (V5) - RFC 4120](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt). Though not an easy read, the article contains embedded references which will explain all of this.  This question was far too broad, as samiles has said.  Please try to start off with a specific programming example next time.